# css rules for mobile website handling

Tags: html, css, mobile

The problem for mobile website is when the screen is landscape, it is widescreen, however, when the screen rotate and change to potartiat, it will become less wider and the CSS rules should be different in order to keep element display consistently. Therefore, I would like to know are there anyway to set when the landscape use landscape.css, when potarait use the potariat .css .  Or I need to specific the css once `$(window).resize{}`?  What is the standard way to handle the difference ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no silver bullet, what you should do depends on your website. Apple has some good documentation describing various approaches:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html

Also have a look at Bootstap, which is an open framework created by Twitter to make things easier. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/